# Any way to reshape plain text data to regular tabular data with dplyr' utilities?

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, data-manipulation

I have gridded data in plain text `ASCII` format ([please take a look original raw data on the fly](http://jmp.sh/v/5EuUYK5wNRDerM8uXAHv)) and all data observations were conducted in daily level where yearly data were collected in grid. However, I want to reconstruct this data because I want to do yearly statistics. To do so, I need to reconstruct this plain text data in matrix-like tabular data where daily data observation is going to be in new columns, so it would be easier to do yearly average.

**update**:

Because original raw plain text data (([please take a look original raw data on the fly](http://jmp.sh/v/5EuUYK5wNRDerM8uXAHv))) is rather big, here I just put general overview of original data.

**update 2**:

I imported original raw plain data in `ASCII` into R, here is the R script down below:

```
rawdata = read.table(file = "~/25_krig_all_1980", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, comment.char="Y", stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
colnames(rawdata) = c("long", "lat", "precip", "err1", "err2")
```

Here is how the skeleton of original raw plain text data looks like ([please take a look on clipped raw data on the fly](http://jmp.sh/v/asYh2RvzCjy32Hu65gPb)) in `notepad++`:

```
1980   1   1   1
      6.125 47.375     0.0    20.00     1.0
      6.375 47.375     0.0    19.99     1.0
      6.625 47.375     0.0    19.97     1.0
      6.875 47.375     0.0    19.84     1.0
      7.125 47.375     0.0    20.00     1.0
 1980   1   2   2
      6.125 47.375     1.5    20.00     1.0
      6.375 47.375     1.5    19.99     1.0
      6.625 47.375     1.5    19.97     1.0
      6.875 47.375     1.5    19.84     1.0
      7.125 47.375     2.9    20.00     1.0
 1980   1   3   3
      6.125 47.375     3.3    20.00     1.0
      6.375 47.375     3.3    19.99     1.0
      6.625 47.375     3.3    19.97     1.0
      6.875 47.375     3.3    19.84     1.0
      7.125 47.375     1.3    20.00     1.0
 1980   1   4   4
      6.125 47.375     3.8    20.00     1.0
      6.375 47.375     3.8    19.99     1.0
      6.625 47.375     3.8    19.97     1.0
      6.875 47.375     3.7    19.84     1.0
      7.125 47.375     3.7    20.00     1.0
 1980   1   5   5
      6.125 47.375     2.2    20.00     1.0
      6.375 47.375     2.2    19.99     1.0
      6.625 47.375     2.2    19.97     1.0
      6.875 47.375     2.2    19.84     1.0
      7.125 47.375     4.8    20.00     1.0
```

Here is my minimal example to explain original raw plain text data:

```
foo = read.table("grid_data_demo.txt", header=FALSE, skip=1, nrows = 5)
colnames(foo) = c("long", "lat", "precip", "err1", "err2")
```

**update 3**:

in original plaintext data, there is no text delimiter, there is no list where all data placed in pure text. I created `miniDat` as a reproducible example because I want to obtain a list like object from original raw data (([please take a look example data snipt on the fly](http://jmp.sh/v/asYh2RvzCjy32Hu65gPb)) )

```
miniDat = list(dat_19800101 = data.frame(long=c( 6.125 ,6.375, 6.625, 6.875, 7.125),
                                         lat=c(47.375, 47.375, 47.375, 47.375, 47.375),
                                         precip=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                                         err1=c(20.00, 19.99, 19.97, 19.84, 20.00),
                                         err2=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)),
               dat_19800102 = data.frame(long=c( 6.125 ,6.375, 6.625, 6.875, 7.125),
                                         lat=c(47.375, 47.375, 47.375, 47.375, 47.375),
                                         precip=c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.9),
                                         err1=c(20.00, 19.99, 19.97, 19.84, 20.00),
                                         err2=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)),

               dat_19800103 = data.frame(long=c( 6.125 ,6.375, 6.625, 6.875, 7.125),
                                         lat=c(47.375, 47.375, 47.375, 47.375, 47.375),
                                         precip=c(3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 1.3),
                                         err1=c(20.00, 19.99, 19.97, 19.84, 20.00),
                                         err2=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)),
               dat_19800104 = data.frame(long=c( 6.125 ,6.375, 6.625, 6.875, 7.125),
                                         lat=c(47.375, 47.375, 47.375, 47.375, 47.375),
                                         precip=c(3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.7, 3.7),
                                         err1=c(20.00, 19.99, 19.97, 19.84, 20.00),
                                         err2=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)),
               dat_19800105 = data.frame(long=c( 6.125 ,6.375, 6.625, 6.875, 7.125),
                                         lat=c(47.375, 47.375, 47.375, 47.375, 47.375),
                                         precip=c(2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 4.8),
                                         err1=c(20.00, 19.99, 19.97, 19.84, 20.00),
                                         err2=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)))
```

So I want to reconstruct matrix-like tabular data from original raw plain text data, and to do yearly statistics for each grid point respectively. Perhaps, `dplyr` or `data.table` provides utilities to handle this sort of manipulation. Is there any quick solution to do this data transformation? How can I make this happen easily in `dplyr` utilities? Any idea?

**desired output**:

in my expected output, I would like to drop the `fourth (err1)` and `fifth (err2)` columns while keep the same dimension of `long` and `lat` column with respetive daily `precip` value as new column. here is reproducible example of my expected output:

```
desired_output = data.frame(
    long=c( 6.125 ,6.375, 6.625, 6.875, 7.125),
    lat=c(47.375, 47.375, 47.375, 47.375, 47.375),
    precip_day1=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    precip_day2=c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.9),
    precip_day3=c(3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 1.3),
    precip_day4=c(3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.7, 3.7),
    precip_day5=c(2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 4.8)
)
```

Basically, I want to simplify original raw data and reconstruct it to matrix-like tabular data for the sake of easier calculation for yearly average `precip` for each grid coordinate. For the simplification and efficiency, in my expected final output, I want to have all `long`, `lat` and `annual_mn_precip` column respectively.

How can I get this data simplification and transformation in R? Any easier way to do this? Thanks

Comment: If you have data for the entire year, 366 columns of precipitation might be unpleasant to deal with, have you considered a tall table with a date , station ID, and precipitation column?

Comment: @MichaelBird there is no `station ID`. in above example, `1980 1 1 1` means `1980-01-01- number of days`. opening original raw data on the fly [link for original raw data](http://jmp.sh/v/5EuUYK5wNRDerM8uXAHv) in `notepad++` is encouraged.  Could you elaborate your thought please?

Comment: I saw you had 5 different Lat Long pairs and assumed each was a different rain station so I just named them with a station id rather than use the lat longs. My comment is only on your choice of desired output as it might get very large. I was suggesting something like: `desired_output <- data.frame(Id = rep(1:5,5),
                             date=rep(seq.Date(as.Date("1980-01-01"),as.Date("1980-01-05"),by=1),each=5),
                             precip=runif(25))`

Comment: @MichaelBird I am going to handle original raw data on the fly ([original data](http://jmp.sh/v/5EuUYK5wNRDerM8uXAHv) ) and find dynamic solution for this orignal data rather than my reproducible example on above. My desired output is just a mockup example where how the skeleton of final output would be.

Comment: Using your `miniDat`, is this what you want? `lapply(1:length(miniDat),function(x){return(mutate(miniDat[[x]],id=x))}) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  select(-err1,-err2) %>%
  spread(key = id,value = precip) `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `readLines` to read the raw text file in to a vector of lines in the file. Then you can identify which lines contain dates and which ones contain observations (based on the indentation in this case); read them into separate data frames; and combine the data frames based on the indices of the rows that contained dates. Here's the code to do just that:

```
parse_weather <- function(file) {
  lines <- readLines(file)

  # Indicators for whether a line contains a date or an observation
  date_lines <- !startsWith(lines, " ")
  data_lines <- !date_lines

  # Number of observations for each date
  nobs <- diff(c(which(date_lines), length(lines) + 1)) - 1

  dates <- read.table(
    # repeat date for each observation
    text = paste(rep(lines[date_lines], nobs), collapse = "\n"),
    col.names = c("year", "month", "day", "days")
  )

  observations <- read.table(
    text = paste(lines[data_lines], collapse = "\n"),
    col.names = c("long", "lat", "precip", "err1", "err2")
  )

  cbind(dates, observations)
}

# I saved the example data snippet as a local text file
weather <- parse_weather("weather.txt")
head(weather, 8)
#>   year month day days  long    lat precip  err1 err2
#> 1 1980     1   1    1 6.125 47.375    0.0 20.00    1
#> 2 1980     1   1    1 6.375 47.375    0.0 19.99    1
#> 3 1980     1   1    1 6.625 47.375    0.0 19.97    1
#> 4 1980     1   1    1 6.875 47.375    0.0 19.84    1
#> 5 1980     1   1    1 7.125 47.375    0.0 20.00    1
#> 6 1980     1   2    2 6.125 47.375    1.5 20.00    1
#> 7 1980     1   2    2 6.375 47.375    1.5 19.99    1
#> 8 1980     1   2    2 6.625 47.375    1.5 19.97    1
```

It's probably easier to work with these data in the long format that this importing strategy leaves them in. If you wanted to have a column for each day though, you could achieve that by reshaping the data with e.g. `tidyr::spread` or `rehsape2::dcast`.

**Edit:** Turns out that `read.table` is very slow with a large vector input given as the `text` argument. Pasting the `lines` vector into a single string makes the process a lot faster for large files: I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: The data in your link aren't formatted like the snippet in your post. The observations are only indented by a single space, rather than two or more. So replace `startsWith(lines, "   ")` with `startsWith(lines, " ")`

Comment: Or you could use a different heuristic for identifying the date lines, such as counting the number of records on the row as in @LenGreski's answer.

Comment: I would wrap it in a function expecting a single argument, the file path, and then apply it on a vector containing the multiple file paths with `lapply`.

Comment: As there is no R-level iteration involved, it can't really be vectorized any further. Performance improvements would have to focus on faster parsing to a data frame. I can have a look later.

Comment: Okay, `read.table` with the `lines` vector was very slow. Simply pasting the `lines` into a single string, separated by new lines, should increase speed significantly. Does the updated answer work better for you?

Comment: thank you very much, updated solution works fast now. BTW, I want to do yearly total precipitation for each grid node, should I should use `tidyr::spread()` to get spreadsheet? Could you point me out how to do?

Comment: @user88911 - Your last comment is a new question. Please post a new question, including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating what you're trying to do and what problem(s) your experiencing.

Comment: I liked your solution a lot, your code is magically fast enough. Great job and thanks for kind help :)

Answer (score 4):

The distinguishing characteristics of this problem are:

1. One header record per day with a variable number of observations / detail records per day
2. The varying detail observation rows do not include a key that links the headers to the detail information
3. Header records have 4 columns, detail records have 5 columns
4. Since a longitude coordinate may have up to 3 digits to the left of the decimal point, we can't parse the records for a blank in the first column to distinguish header records from detail records

The most straightfoward way to read this file and align the header information with the details is to leverage text processing to reshape the file so it contains one observation per record. Once the raw data is reshaped, it can be easily read with `read.table()`.

The required transformations be accomplished in base R with a combination of `readLines()` and `lapply()`.

```
inFile <- "./data/tempdata1980.txt"
outputFile <- "./data/tempData.txt"
# delete output file if it already exists
if (file.exists(outputFile)) file.remove(outputFile)
theText <- readLines(inFile)
header <- NULL # scope to retain header across executions of lapply()
theResult <- lapply(theText,function(x){
     # reduce blanks to 1 between tokens 
     aRow <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", x, perl = TRUE)," "))
     # use <<- form of assignment operator to set to parent of if() environment 
     if (length(aRow) == 4) header <<- x
     else {
          cat(paste(header,x),file=outputFile,
              sep="\n",append=TRUE)
     }
})
# now read with read.table
colNames <- c("year","month","day","dayOfYear","long","lat","precip","err1","err2")
theData <- read.table(outputFile,header=FALSE,col.names = colNames)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(theData)
  year month day dayOfYear  long    lat precip  err1 err2
1 1980     1   1         1 6.125 47.375    0.0 20.00    1
2 1980     1   1         1 6.375 47.375    0.0 19.99    1
3 1980     1   1         1 6.625 47.375    0.0 19.97    1
4 1980     1   1         1 6.875 47.375    0.0 19.84    1
5 1980     1   1         1 7.125 47.375    0.0 20.00    1
6 1980     1   2         2 6.125 47.375    1.5 20.00    1
>
```

This approach also avoids having to track the number of observations per day in order to merge the header records with the correct number of detail records.

### UPDATE: Improving performance of the solution

Per comments to this answer, the script takes considerable amount of time to execute against the complete data referenced in the OP. The raw data file has 407,705 lines: 365 header records and 407,340 detail records. The solution described above transforms the data and loads it into a data frame in about 155 seconds on a MacBook Pro with the following configuration.

- Operating system: OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 (14E46)
- Processor: Intel i5 at 2.6Ghz, turbo up to 3.3Ghz, two cores
- Memory: 8 gigabytes
- Disk: 512 gigabytes, solid state drive
- Date built: April 2013

### Causes of slow performance

In comparison to the other answer provided to the post, there are two potential sources of slowness, including:

1. Use of string functions `gsub()` and `strsplit()`, one of which generates a list of strings as its output
2. Use of `cat(...,append=TRUE)` within a loop, which means that R must open the file, navigate to the end, and add content over 400,000 times.

### Performance optimizations

We adjusted the code in the following ways to improve its performance.

1. Used the `readr` library for reads and writes because it runs much faster than base R functions
2. Write the output from `lapply()` to a vector in memory rather than writing to disk during the execution of `lapply()`, and
3. Write the output vector once with `readr::write_lines()`

The updated version runs in approximately 23 seconds, quite an improvement over the original. The modified code and performance times are listed below.

```
inFile <- "./data/25_krig_all_1980.txt"
outputFile <- "./data/tempData.txt"
if (file.exists(outputFile)) file.remove(outputFile)
library(readr)
system.time(theText <- readLines(inFile))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.821   0.027   1.859 

header <- NULL # scope to retain header across executions of lapply()
outVector <- NULL
i <- 1 
system.time(theResult <- lapply(theText,function(x){
     # reduce blanks to 1 between tokens 
     aRow <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", x, perl = TRUE)," "))
     # use <<- form of assignment operator to set to parent of if() environment 
     if (length(aRow) == 4) header <<- x
     else {
          outVector[i] <<- paste(header,x)
          i <<- i + 1
     }
}))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 19.327   0.085  19.443 

# write to file
system.time(write_lines(outVector,outputFile))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.079   0.020   0.117 

# now read with read.table
colNames <- c("year","month","day","dayOfYear","long","lat","precip","err1","err2")
system.time(theData <- read_table2(outputFile,col_names = colNames))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.559   0.071   0.794
```

### One final optimization

The other answer to the OP checked to see whether the first column on a record was blank in order to decide whether the record is a header or a detail record. At the top of my post I noted that since longitudes may have 3 digits before the decimal place, this technique is risky.

However, it turns out that this data does not have longitudes greater than 100 degrees east or west of the prime meridian, so we can improve the runtime performance of our script with the following code.

```
header <- NULL # scope to retain header across executions of lapply()
outVector <- NULL
i <- 1
system.time(theResult <- lapply(theText,function(x){
     # use <<- form of assignment operator to set to parent of if() environment 
     if (substr(x,1,1) != " ") header <<- x
     else {
          outVector[i] <<- paste(header,x)
          i <<- i + 1
     }
}))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.840   0.080   2.933
```

As we can see from the performance timings, replacing `strsplit()` with a simple substring comparison improves runtime of the `lapply()` step from almost 20 seconds to about 3 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. Regarding your solution, is there any vectorized solution so it works fast even larger data?

Comment: @user88911 - I will post an updated solution that performs faster within the next 24 hours

Comment: @user88911 - performance optimizations and explanatory text have been added to my answer.